# Know which item selected?

Tags: android, button, android-alertdialog

I have an application where you can select an item from a AlertDialog spinner like, but I don't know how to make my app, to memorize the selected choice, and then behave my button to this. This is what I have now:

```
@Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.ais);
                    mp.start();
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
                    MainActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
                }
            }, 9000);
            Intent i = new Intent();
            i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}
```

And somehow to this code, I want to add my last selected item button, for example:

If ( last selected item from AlertDialog was = dance)

do the code, that I wrote above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is with an **interface**. Define an interface in your Alert Dialog fragment and instantiate it like this:

```
public interface MyDialogListener {
    //put whatever data you want to pass as a paramenter, below I have two examples
    public void onDataSelectedEvent( String action); 
}

MyDialogListener myListener;
```

The listener will have to be instantiated in the dialog by typecasting your activity to a `MyDialogListener`.

You could do it like this:

```
myListener = (MyDialogListener) MainActivity.this;
```

Or even better would be to use the *activity* parameter in the dialog's `onAttach(...)` method.

We are able to do this because later, we will make your activity implement the MyDialogListener interface, which will effectively make the activity a MyDialogListener.

Put this line in the method or listener, maybe an onClick() in your alert dialog. This is for a spinner:

```
myListener.onDataSelectedEvent(mySpinner.getSelectedItem().toString())
```

Implement the **interface** in your **Activity** that receives the data like this:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity
                      implements MyAlertDialog.MyDialogListener{
```

Then, in the activity receiving the data, have the interface method look like this:

```
@Override
public void onDataSelectedEvent(String action) {

    //probably better to use a switch statement
    if(action == "dance") {
         // dance()
    } else if(action == "stand") {
      .......etc 
    }
}
```

There is a good example here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#PassingEvents